# Как организовать следующую задачу c#

Tags: c#, классы, структуры, полиморфизм

Есть абстрактный класс "Работник" с абстрактным методом "Подсчитать зараплату", от него наследуются два класса реализующие этот метод, "Наёмный работник" зарплата считается за кол-во подрядов. И "Штатный работник" со своей схемой подсчета.
В абстрактном классе есть поля ФИО, у классов-наследников есть свои индивидуальные поля, и методы для их изменения/считывания (типо get set).
В программе есть список состоящий из классов "Работник", и два метода добавления нового работника, первый для наёмника второй для штатного (с разными полями разумеется). Эти методы приводят наследников к базовому абстрактному.

Вопрос: Как реализовать возможность редактирования полей классов-наследников, ведь если мы приведём их к базовому, то потеряем доступ к индивидуальным полям. и сможем отредактировать только ФИО?

Comment: Ничего вы не теряете, просто ссылки которые будет хранить коллекция, будут иметь тип базового класса, делайте приведение типов и все.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IEditor {
  bool Edit(Worker worker);
}

public static class Editors {
  private static List<IEditor> items = new List<IEditor>();

  public static RegisterEditor(IEditor item) {
    items.Add(item);
  }

  public static bool Edit(Worker worker) {
    foreach(IEditor editor in items) {
      if (editor.Edit(worker))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
} 

public class Editor_TempHire : IEditor {
  public bool Edit(Worker worker) {
    if (worker is Worker_TempHire) {
      Worker_TempHire th = (Worker_TempHire)worker;
      // edit th
      // ...
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

public class Editor_FullTime : IEditor {
  public bool Edit(Worker worker) {
    if (worker is Worker_FullTime) {
      Worker_FullTime ft = (Worker_FullTime)worker;
      // edit ft
      // ...
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

Editors.RegisterEditor(new Editor_TempHire);
Editors.RegisterEditor(new Editor_FullTime);

Worker worker = ...
if (!Editors.Edit(worker)) {
  throw new EditorNotFoundException(worker);
}
```

Comment: Зачем статика, у вас же получился типичный композит :)

Comment: @tym32167 Возможны варианты :).